# VBScript. Move a file and rename it with increment if exists

Tags: vbscript, increment, file-move

I'm trying to create a vbscript that moves files from one directory to another, that increments the filename if the file allready exists. I.e. if file.ext exists, new filename is file_01.ext. If file_01.ext exists, new filename is file_02.ext, and so on. I can't get it to work. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```vb
Const cVBS = "Vaskedama.vbs"     '= script name
Const cLOG = "Vaskedama.log"     '= log filename
Const cFOL = "C:\fra\"          '= source folder
Const cMOV = "C:\til\"              '= dest. folder
Const cDAZ = -1                      '= # days

Dim strMSG
    strMSG = " files moved from " & cFOL & " to " & cMOV
MsgBox Move_Files(cFOL) & strMSG,vbInformation,cVBS

Function Move_Files(folder)
    Move_Files = 0

    Dim strDAT
    Dim intDAZ
    Dim arrFIL()
  ReDim arrFIL(0)
    Dim intFIL
        intFIL = 0
    Dim strFIL
    Dim intLEN
        intLEN = 0
    Dim strLOG
        strLOG = "echo " & cVBS & " -- " & Now & vbCrLf
    Dim dtmNOW
        dtmNOW = Now

    Dim objFSO
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim objGFO
    Dim objGFI

    If Not objFSO.FolderExists(cFOL) _
    Or Not objFSO.FolderExists(cMOV) Then
        MsgBox "A folder does not exist!",vbExclamation,cVBS
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set objGFO = objFSO.GetFolder(folder)
    Set objGFI = objGFO.Files

    For Each strFIL In objGFI
        strDAT = strFIL.DateCreated
        intDAZ = DateDiff("d",strDAT,dtmNOW)
        If intDAZ > cDAZ Then
            intFIL = intFIL + 1
            ReDim Preserve arrFIL(intFIL)
            arrFIL(intFIL) = strFIL.Name
            If intLEN < Len(strFIL.Name) Then
                intLEN = Len(strFIL.Name)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    For intFIL = 1 To UBound(arrFIL)
        strFIL = arrFIL(intFIL)
        Do While (objFSO.FileExists(cMOV & strFIL))
        strFil = CreateNewName(strFIL, intFIL)
        Loop
        objFSO.MoveFile folder & strFIL, cMOV & strFIL
        strLOG = strLOG & "move " & folder & strFIL _
               & Space(intLEN-Len(strFIL)+1) _
               & cMOV & strFIL & vbCrLf
    Next

    Set objGFI = Nothing
    Set objGFO = Nothing
        strLOG = strLOG & "echo " & UBound(arrFIL) & " files moved"
        objFSO.CreateTextFile(cLOG,True).Write(strLOG)
    Set objFSO = Nothing

    Move_Files = UBound(arrFIL)
End Function

Function CreateNewName(strValue, intValue)
    CreateNewName = strValue & intValue
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

As I can't understand your script at all, I'll concentrate on the the task "build a new file name by incrementing a counter". Obviously you have to check for each file whether there is a file with the same name or this name + suffix in the destination folder. The answer to this question for file a is completely independent of all files in the source folder - so I doubt your array makes any sense.

In code:

```
  Const cnMax = 3

  Dim goFS    : Set goFS    = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  Dim oSrcDir : Set oSrcDir = goFS.GetFolder("..\testdata\FancyRename\from")
  Dim sDstDir : sDstDir     = "..\testdata\FancyRename\to"
  Dim oFile, nInc, sNFSpec
  For Each oFile In oSrcDir.Files
      WScript.Echo "looking at", oFile.Name
      nInc    = 0
      sNFSpec = getNewFSpec(oFile.Name, sDstDir, nInc)
      Do While goFS.FileExists(sNFSpec) And nInc <= cnMax
         sNFSpec = getNewFSpec(oFile.Name, sDstDir, nInc)
      Loop
      If nInc > cnMax Then
         WScript.Echo "won't copy to", sNFSpec
      Else
         WScript.Echo "will copy to ", sNFSpec
         oFile.Copy sNFSpec
      End If
  Next

Function getNewFSpec(ByVal sFName, sDstDir, ByRef nInc)
  If 0 < nInc Then
     Dim sSfx
     sSfx = goFS.GetExtensionName(sFName)
     If "" <> sSfx Then sSfx = "." & sSfx
     sSfx = "_" & Right("00" & nInc, 2) & sSfx
     sFName = goFS.GetBaseName(sFName) & sSfx
  End If
  nInc        = nInc + 1
  getNewFSpec = goFS.BuildPath(sDstDir, sFName)
End Function
```

some sample output:

```
looking at B.txt
will copy to  ..\testdata\FancyRename\to\B.txt
looking at C.txt
will copy to  ..\testdata\FancyRename\to\C.txt
looking at A.txt
will copy to  ..\testdata\FancyRename\to\A.txt

looking at B.txt
will copy to  ..\testdata\FancyRename\to\B_01.txt

looking at B.txt
won't copy to ..\testdata\FancyRename\to\B_03.txt
```